# Separate driver file for browser selenium python base

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to have a separate file for browser driver, in my driver file with a file name driver.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver

class MyDriver():
  def __init__(self):
     self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I try reusing it on another file here's the code:

```
from driver import MyDriver
driver = MyDriver()
driver.get('http://google.com')
```

However, I always got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'MyDriver' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to add another **driver**. Try this:

```
driver.driver.get('http://google.com')
```